# Gremlin DFS/BFS Search while avoiding Loops

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

In Gremlin I am trying to get find all the connected nodes in my graph - Using either BFS or DFS I am not worried about the traversal method as I will have a list of edges that will show the connections between the nodes where the output would be something like

```
[
 Nodes : [ {id : 1, name: "abc"}, "{id: 2, name : "pqr"],
 Edges : [ {id : 100, label : ParentOf, from : 1, to : 2 }, {id : 101, label : ChildOf, from : 2, to : 1 }]
]
```

My Graph Looks something like this

[image]

My issues are with cycles - I am trying to emit only the nodes that are connected, say I start with the node 1

```
g.V('a07771c3-8657-4535-8302-60bcdac5b753').repeat(out('knows')).until(__.not(outE('knows'))).path().
       unfold().dedup().id().fold()
```

I end up with the error

```
Gremlin Query Execution Error: Exceeded maximum number of loops on a repeat() step. Cannot exceed 32 loops. Recommend limiting the number of loops using times(n) step or with a loops() condition
```

I am looking for a way where the query skips the nodes that are already emited? Not exactly sure how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `simplePath` step can be used to prevent cycles.

```
g.V('a07771c3-8657-4535-8302-60bcdac5b753').
  repeat(out('knows').simplePath()).
  until(__.not(outE('knows'))).path().
  unfold().
  dedup().
  id().
  fold()
```

Comment: `g.V('a07771c3-8657-4535-8302-60bcdac5b753').
  repeat(out('knows').simplePath())`
this leads to an empty output - i am considering an example where "A" Knows "B", "B" knows "C" and "C" knows "A"

Comment: You still need to include the `until` part as I showed in my answer. You can also try using `until(cyclicPath())`

Comment: So you can have an `until` that looks something like `until(not(out()).or().cyclicPath())`

Comment: I think i figured out my mistake as to why
`g.V('a07771c3-8657-4535-8302-60bcdac5b753').   repeat(out('knows').simplePath())` this was not working - i was missing .emit() at the end, thank you this helped